# Integrate my 3rd party service with customer's ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I built an integration between my service and my customers' serviceNow accounts.

This integration lets my service do the following:

1. CRUD actions over records in a specific custom table on a customer's ServiceNow account.
2. List all users (from the users table) of each customer's ServiceNow account.

Currently in order to establish this integration, each customer has to manually do the following:

1. Create OAuth application in his account and provide my with the client ID and client secret.
2. Create a dedicated user for my service, assign some roles to it, and send me the username and password.
3. Create a custom table based on a provided schema.

Once I get all credentials (app & user) from the customer, I use ServiceNow REST API in order to acquire token, and then I use this token in order to perform the CRUD actions, etc.

I want to simplify the onboarding process, by reducing the amount of manual work each customer has to do:

1. Ideally, avoid the step of creating an application (can he grant consent to a predefined application on my account?)
2. Avoid the step of creating user, if that's possible (can I assign roles to my application? so that no user is needed?)
3. Avoid the step of manually creating the table, and let my service do it on the customer's ServiceNow account through API (assuming I don't need to have a super privileged role in order to do it).

I know I can probably create an application in ServiceNow store, and then customers can install it by a single click but I'm not sure exactly how does it work, and what will this application exactly be able to do? also I still don't have access to the store, I'm working on getting it, so would like to avoid this solution for now, if possible.

What are the options I have in order to simplify the integration process with and without publishing my own application to serviceNow store?

Even avoiding 1 out of the 3 manual steps I described before can be very meaningful in improving the process of establishing the integration.